# Active class for the slider

Tags: jquery, css

Guys Im just stuck in this, Giving an active class. its just simply not working for me - I will show the code, it may let you help me faster. I know the Jquery logic behind the theory but in practical its just NOT done anyway. Thats the reason I came over to ask that.
Its there on http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dZ9KP/12/ .

```
<div id="MainContainer">
  <ul id="MainNav">
    <li> <a href="#page1">   title 1  </a>     </li>
    <li>    <a  href="#page2">  title 2 </a>     </li>                
  </ul>
  <div id="MainContent">
    <div class="MainContentEach" id="page1">
      title 1 content
    </div>
    <div class="MainContentEach" id="page2">
      title 2 content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
     $(function () {
        $('#MainNav a').click(function () {
        pageId = $(this).attr('href');
        num = $('#MainNav a').index(this);
        $(pageId).parent().animate({ scrollTop: (500 * num) }, 'slow');
        });
      });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please elaborate more on your question and better set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: You can import it under add resources.

Comment: Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dZ9KP/12/

Comment: Two items : a) **Do not place meta commentary in a post** (guess what, it's not too bad for us).  If you have issue with a post being closed, take it to [Meta] or flag for moderator attention b) **Do *not* change a question completely that ruins the context of existing answers because another question of yours is closed.**  Edit *that* question to clear up the issues listed in the close reason and possibly the comments.  I'm locking this post for a bit so you can't make destructive edits such as the one that you did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only need to add a class called `active` to the `<a>` tag when its clicked you could do something like this:

```
$(function () {
    $('#MainNav a').click(function () {
         pageId = $(this).attr('href');
         num = $('#MainNav a').index(this);
         $(pageId).parent().animate({ scrollTop: (500 * num) }, 'slow');

         $('#MainNav a').each(function () {
             if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
                 $(this).removeClass('active');
             }
         });

         if (!$(this).hasClass('active')) {
             $(this).addClass('active');
         }
    });
});
```

This will add a class called `active` your `<a>` tag, keep in mind this class will need to be defined in your stylesheet.

Comment: Thank you Steven for the reply. But its giving the class to every <a> clicked !!!!

Comment: @WillySmith Give my updated answer a try, first it will remove all active classes, then it should only set the active class for the <a> tag that was clicked

Comment: Perfect :) Thank you again Steven ; May I know which reference you've learnt jquery from?